# Looking for good Lisp code to read

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Examples of excellent Common Lisp code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585591/examples-of-excellent-common-lisp-code)

I'm currently trying to get proficient in Common Lisp and to learn some of the tricks for writing compact, clear and beautiful code in it.

So, I want to know if you have any sources of good Common Lisp, preferably free and online but books are also OK.

Comment: Yes, indeed looks like the same question. My bad!

Answer (score 5):

The most admirable modern Common Lisp I've seen is in [Edi Weitz's libraries](http://www.weitz.de/). (Look within the outline area *NerdStuff/Common Lisp/Code available on this server*.) His [CL-PPCRE library](http://www.weitz.de/cl-ppcre/) is worth studying in depth.

Answer (score 3):

Large codebases can be *schizophrenic*, because there are often many contributors to the project. I would also say that contributors tend to want to add new features rather than re-write some code because it could be coded in a slightly more elegant way.

Paul Graham is attributed with [good coding style](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/academics/courses/325/readings/graham/graham-notes.html). The link points to pages where his coding style in *ANSI Common Lisp* is commented upon.

Peter Norvig has also written about good Lisp coding style [here](http://lispm.dyndns.org/documentation/norvig-lisp-style.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

**Practical Common Lisp**

Complete book (HTML) is free.

http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should've mentioned that I've read through it already. It was indeed a nice read, but I'm looking for more code and less talk, so to say. Possibly a medium to big code base of some project that is using Lisp idioms in a beautiful way.

Answer (score 1):

Most open source Common Lisp (CL) environments ship with a lot of CL source code.

Take a look at [CMUCL](http://www.cons.org/cmucl/), [CLISP](http://clisp.cons.org/) and [SBCL](http://sbcl.sourceforge.net/).

[Cliki](http://www.cliki.net/index) (the Common Lisp Wiki) has many open source CL packages.

[Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch/advanced_code_search?hl=en) is another large repository of CL code.  Setting the language to "Lisp" will return both CL and non-CL files, like Emacs Lisp (.el) files.  To narrow the results, set the Files text box to .lisp$ so only file names that end in .lisp are returned.

Answer (score 1):

[Paradigms of AI Programming](http://norvig.com/paip.html). The code is online, though the book itself is not to be missed.

[On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html) is also very fine.